# Android - how to make the UI interact with a Java wrapper class

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I have a class that is basically a wrapper for an online api (used to use HttpClient but noticed the benefit/requirement of async tasks and chose to do it with Retrofit). Problem since porting it to Retrofit is that I dont have any ideas how to properly make the Java class (Wrapper) interact with my Activity.

I have read a lot of stackoverflow posts, tried it with an interface in the OnFinished event of retrofit, where I pass the interface to the method and then set the variable of the method in the interface. Then in the activity I did

```
Entries entries = new MyWrapper().SearchRequest(someParameter, new ApiCallback(){

void onSearchRequestFinished(Entries entries){
//here I use the entries
}
}
```

In the wrapper it looked like this:

```
 RequestBody postBodyObj = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), postBody);
    Call<Entries> call = mInterface.searchRequest(postBodyObj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Entries>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Entries> call, retrofit2.Response<Entries> response) {
            Entries entries = response.body();
            callback.onSearchRequestFinished(entries);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Entries> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

The problem with this is that it seems to always return null/the parameter is not set. If I check or even log the entries in the wrapper class (in the OnFinished class from RetroFit) its not null.

Maybe I do this completely wrong or maybe I just need to design my interaction better (do webrequests in the activity?)

Thanks!

Comment: Which is `null`, `callback` or `entries`?

Comment: Entries in the activity. So in the first code example the entries, which should be the result from the searchrequest, is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it, I will just use [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Here's  nice tutorial how to use it with retrofit: [link](https://github.com/JaimeToca/RetrofitOttoExample)